# Galeria de imagens CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, galeria

Estou tentanto fazer uma galeria de imagens para um site, peguei uma demonstração que achei na internet e estou tentando editar ela, porém eu gostaria de modificar para a minitura das imagens ficar intercalada, uma pra esquerda e uma pra direita, mas não descobri um jeito de fazer. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda ? o CSS está muito grande para mandar por aqui, mas se precisar eu mando. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"> <!-- CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> <!-- Resource style -->
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->

    <title>Farol Filmes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="gotham">
        <h1></h1>
    </header>

    <section class="cd-single-item">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected"><img src="img/teste.jpeg" ></li>
                <li><img src="img/img-2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="img/img-3.jpg"></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li><a href="#0" class="cd-prev inactive">Next</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" class="cd-next">Prev</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->

            <a href="#0" class="cd-close">fechar</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2 class="gotham">Casamento Yo e Gui</h2>

            <p class="gotham-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione.</p>

        </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
    </section> <!-- cd-single-item -->

    <section class=" gotham-light cd-content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem, quisquam veniam sequi in quasi excepturi laudantium fugit nihil odio minima quae consequuntur dolorum pariatur obcaecati, adipisci dignissimos officia saepe itaque deleniti porro odit vitae voluptate. Blanditiis sunt obcaecati corporis, alias adipisci. Eum illum voluptatibus expedita nulla eius provident pariatur!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem, quisquam veniam sequi in quasi excepturi laudantium fugit nihil odio minima quae consequuntur dolorum pariatur obcaecati, adipisci dignissimos officia saepe itaque deleniti porro odit vitae voluptate.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section class="cd-single-item">
        <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
            <ul class="cd-slider">
                <li class="selected"><img src="img/teste.jpeg" ></li>
                <li><img src="img/img-2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="img/img-3.jpg"></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->

            <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
                <li><a href="#0" class="cd-prev inactive">Next</a></li>
                <li><a href="#0" class="cd-next">Prev</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->

            <a href="#0" class="cd-close">fechar</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->

        <div class="cd-item-info">
            <h2 class="gotham">Casamento Yo e Gui</h2>

            <p class="gotham-light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, omnis illo iste ratione.</p>

        </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
    </section> <!-- cd-single-item -->

    <section class=" gotham-light cd-content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem, quisquam veniam sequi in quasi excepturi laudantium fugit nihil odio minima quae consequuntur dolorum pariatur obcaecati, adipisci dignissimos officia saepe itaque deleniti porro odit vitae voluptate. Blanditiis sunt obcaecati corporis, alias adipisci. Eum illum voluptatibus expedita nulla eius provident pariatur!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum voluptatem, quisquam veniam sequi in quasi excepturi laudantium fugit nihil odio minima quae consequuntur dolorum pariatur obcaecati, adipisci dignissimos officia saepe itaque deleniti porro odit vitae voluptate.
        </p>
    </section>
```

[Site CodyHouse - Source](https://codyhouse.co/gem/expandable-image-gallery)

Comment: Jovem vc precisa mesmo dessa biblioteca para fazer algo tão simples? Com CSS vc resolve isso fácil... Se estiver usando Bootstrap 4 ai é que não precisa mesmo desse esquema ai...

Comment: Na verdade tô usando esse modelo por que ele combina bem com o estilo do site que estou fazendo. Com Bootstrap tem como fazer algo parecido ?

Comment: O esquema de abrir a galeria com o carrocel seria bem mais complicado, mas colocar uma imagem de cada lado alternando com o conteúdo seria bem tranquilo

Comment: Nessa caso vou deixar desse jeito mesmo, por que precisaria do carrousel por que cada linha seria um ensaio fotográfico e precisaria do carrocel. Obrigado

Comment: Entendi.. Eu dei uma customizada lá no CSS da galeria. Acho que ficou como vc quer. Coloca o CSS da resposta no CSS do componente lá, e coloca a classe `.direita` na section que vc quer a galeria a direita. Os detalhes estão na resposta qq coisa comenta lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha para fazer o que vc quer tipo a imagem abaixo vc vai ter que fazer algumas adaptações no CSS, é pouca coisa! Mas fazem toda a diferença. Não precisa mexer no HTML e na estrutura ou ordem das tags, vc vai resolver tudo com CSS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro vc precisa ter em mente que vc vai usar isso só para as galerias que vc quer a direita (sua posição customizada). Então crie uma classe tipo `.direta` e coloque na section que vai ter a galeria na `direita`

**OBS Importante:** Repare que em todas as *classe* eu inclui `.cd-single-item.direita` antes. Isso é porque eu só quero esse CSS nessa section que determinei que a galeria deve ficar a direita `<section class="cd-single-item direita">`

***Deixei uns comentários no CSS para vc entender onde mudei***

Segue o CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.cd-single-item.direita .cd-slider-wrapper.direita {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%; /* aqui alinho a galeria a direita */
}
.cd-single-item.direita .cd-slider-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: width .4s;
    -moz-transition: width .4s;
    transition: all .4s; /* aqui habilito a animação também para o margin */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: width;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.cd-single-item.direita .cd-slider-active .cd-slider-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0; /* aqui coloco a galeria crescendo para esquerda e não para direita como a original */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.cd-single-item.direita .cd-item-info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    /* right: 0;  retire o right para jogar o conteúdo para esquerda */
    padding: 60px 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Cara, então eu tentei implementar no meu css o que você passou e não deu muito certo, (https://gifs.com/gif/erro-jqpjOY), ao lado segue gif de como ficou. 
http://prntscr.com/kzhtq1 - Esse é como eu deixei o html, coloquei a classe direita na section e na div. http://prntscr.com/kzhuax - E esse é o css que você me passou, só não entedi a parte de criar a classe .direita o que eu precisava colocar, desculpa a ignorancia, mas é que não entendi direito como implementar.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa é que se vc não criar uma classe diferente pra cada galeria todas vão ficar a direita. e vc não vai conseguir intercalar uma de cada lado entende. Não precisa colocar a classe `direita` na DIV, só na Section! Mesmo assim não sei dizer pq não funcionou ai... Vc tem esse site publicado em algum lugar? Faz um teste rápido ai, coloca lá no final do seu CSS essas mesmas classes ai da resposta, mas retira isso da frente do dos nomes das classes `.cd-single-item.direita` ai testa com o resto do CSS pra ver se funciona. **Não coloca .direita em nada e testa** Qq coisa me fala

Comment: Então, fiz isso ai de tirar todos os .direita e apagar .cd-single-item.direita e ficou tudo na direita e funcionou o carrocel quando clica, conforme o print (http://prntscr.com/kzi8ru), mas o texto ficou por baixo da imagem. O CSS assim (http://prntscr.com/kzia3o). O que pode ser que fiz errado ?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa nessa classe coloca um "left: 0" além do restante do CSS que já tem lá:  `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.cd-single-item.direita .cd-item-info { ... left: 0 !important ... }` o `right: 0`continua comentado ok, não use o right. Se ainda assim não rolar inclua um `margin-right: auto;` junto com esse `left:0` e olha se o conteúdo que ficou por baixo alinha na esquerda!

Comment: Não deu certo, eu upei ele num servidor pra você dar uma olhada (https://goo.gl/4q9TnL). Do jeito que ta upado ali, está sem a class `.direita`. Quando coloco a classe .direita da aquele problema do gif que mandei antes.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa cara olha ai! Fí só colocar o `left:0` veja se foi nessa classe mesmo que vc mexeu. https://imgur.com/4Iy30W0 `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)
.cd-single-item .cd-item-info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 60px 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* right: 0; */
    left: 0;
}`

Comment: agora deu certo, não sei pq kkkkk, só não entendi por que com `.direita`não funcionou. Quer que eu upe pra você dar uma olhada o que fiz errado ?

Comment: @LucasCorrêa acho que foi pq vc colocou essa class .direita em alguns lugares que não precisava rss... Mas vai saber.... Vc pode criar a mesma classe inteirinha na íntegra e só mudar o nome no final tipo `.cd-slider-wrapper-teste { copiar o css para alinhar a direita }` depois coloca essa classe onde precisar. Pode ter sido a hierarquia das classes tb, isso é quando um estilo de outra classe está sobrescrevendo o seu, vc pode pesquisar sobre isso que vai te ajudar! Vc acha que agora resolveu a questão? Se a resposta te ajudou considere marcar o `✔` :)

Comment: Acho que deu quase tudo certo, só um único probleminha que não consegui resolver, (http://prntscr.com/kzj651) <-- esse fechar era pra ser um icone de fechar, mas não sei o que preciso fazer para ele voltar. Vou deixar aqui o print de como está o CSS (http://prntscr.com/kzj71s) e o HTML (http://prntscr.com/kzj7or) 
LINK DO SITE UPADO (https://goo.gl/4q9TnL).

Comment: @LucasCorrêa cara mas cade as classes do seu btn fechar?? Vc apagou ou nem chegou a colocar? Está tudo lá no site oficial, basta vc inspecionar o btn com o DevTools.. Olha ai o CSS do btn fechar antes de clicar na galerai https://imgur.com/5bFnrh2 e aqui como o box vermelho o CSS depois que a galeria esta aberta. https://imgur.com/pcDdFBx ... Vc pode pegar o CSS direto no site inspecionando o btn fechar X da galeria depois de aberta

Comment: No desktop consegui deixar ok, porém quando é abaixo de 1024px eu não to conseguindo arrumar a questão do fechar, CSS(http://prntscr.com/kzjs39), eu preciso criar outra tag de `@media` ? E o `.cd-info` está menor que deveria também e não cosegui descobrir por que. Acredito que seja minha última dúvida rsrs, desculpa fazer tantas perguntas. Site: https://goo.gl/4q9TnL .

Comment: @LucasCorrêa cara o Btn fechar est[a no tamanho correto, pelo menos no seu site e no site do exemplo eles estão do mesmo tamanho. Com relação a telas menores vc pelo que vi no exemplo em telas menores nem tem a opção de expandir a galeria, assim como não deveria aparecer o btn de fechar, vc deve ter mexido em algum CSS ai e colocou display:block em algum lugar... De qq forma tente assim `@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px)
.cd-slider-wrapper .cd-close {
    display: none !important;
}`

Comment: Cara, conseguir dar um jeito de consertar aqui, muito obrigado pelas dicas, foi de grande de ajuda.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa boa jovem! Essa foi complicada de fazer dar certo, mas que bom que resolveu e ficou com vc queria. CSS tem horas que é complicado de entender, mas com calma a "ficha cai" e a gente entende como fazer funcionar. Boa sorte ai com o projeto!